# How to find index of a JSON array in Angular4?

Tags: json, angular

I have a JSON array:

```
data = [{"user_id":22},{"user_id":12}];
```

1) I need to find the index of an element. I use the method:

```
     var value = 22;
     var index = -1;
     var res = this.data.find(function(item, i){
      if(item.user_id === val){
      index = i;
      return i;
      }
     });
     console.log(index, res);
```

But the problem is that I got index `0` all the time.

2) I need to use the same array in the format:

```
"test" :{
        "users":[{"user_id":22},
                 {"user_id":12}
                ]
      }
```

when I use this format:

```
"test":{
        "users":this.data
        }
```

but it gives Array(0).

I didn't find anything wrong. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: This should be a javascript question not angular

Answer (score 1):

Use `findIndex` method

```
var indexNum =[{"user_id":22},{"user_id":12}].findIndex((element)=> {
  return (element.user_id == 22);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `findIndex` for this

```
data = [{"user_id":22},{"user_id":12}];

let indx =data.findIndex(item=>item.user_id == 12);
```